# Creating a very simple jQuery plugin, not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I've never created a jQuery plug-in before.  I'm trying it out and keeping it simple for now- here's my plug-in code which is hosted on a CDN in my company:

```
(function ($) {

    $.fn.displayToastrNotifications = function () {
        alert('test');
    };

})(jQuery);
```

I'm referencing this JavaScript file inside my page:

```
<script src="http://server/sites/CDN/Scripts/toastr-notifications.js"></script>
```

Finally, in the same page, I have:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $.displayToastrNotifications();
});
```

Am I doing this right?  The JavaScript file containing my plug-in code is being brought back to the browser per Firebug.  I do not get an alert box when I refresh my page.  What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

The console reports an error:

> TypeError: $.displayToastrNotifications is not a function
>
> $.displayToastrNotifications();

But, it is a function, at least I think it is...

Comment: Any error in the `console`?

Comment: you should have an error saying `has no method 'displayToastrNotifications' `

Comment: @ArunPJohny Okay, so... you're right.  This is the problem... any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, that's not right. You're adding the function to `$.fn`, so that means it's something to be used as a method of jQuery objects:

```
$(something).displayToastrNotifications();
```

If you want a "global" function like `$.ajax`, then you'd set it up as just a property of `$`, not `$.fn`.

Answer (score 4):

since it is a plugin it need to be invoked in a jQuery wrapper object like

```
$('body').displayToastrNotifications();
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/WX4jS/)

Comment: Thank you, I gave the other guy the answer because not only did he explain why it didn't work, he explained how to make my code work as it was.